# Existem outras bibliotecas de interface gráfica, além da awt, swing e javafx?

Tags: java, swing, framework, aplicação-desktop

Queria detalhes e para que servem essas bibliotecas para me ajudar a desenvolver o meu software para videolocadora.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, se existir eu não sei avaliar se vale a pena utilizar, até porque nunca ouvi falar e não sei como é.

O que eu posso falar é sobre esses três que você menciona no titulo.

#### AWT

O AWT foi a primeira biblioteca para criação de interface para desktop, criada na primeira versão do Java. O maior feito dessa biblioteca era ter uma identidade visual abstrata, dessa forma o seu estilo iria variar dependendo do sistema operacional utilizado, ou seja, em um Mac o seu programa iria ser diferente visualmente do Windows ou outros.
Porém era uma biblioteca bem precária quando falamos em questão de recursos pra criação de telas e também nada bonito.

#### SWING

Swing veio logo depois, na versão 1.2 do Java, exatamente com a ideia de ter uma identidade visual mais bonita que a do precário AWT, mas como podemos perceber pela história, nunca foi a intenção de quem cuidava do Java alcançar o mercado Desktop, por isso, novamente foi uma biblioteca que não atendia de forma satisfatória, pois sempre foi complicado lidar com ela e ainda tinha uma identidade visual feia.

#### JavaFX

E finalmente, chegamos ao JavaFX, a última e real tentativa do Java alcançar o mercado Desktop. Com certeza é de longe o melhor dos três e uma boa ferramenta pra desenvolver, porém, chegou muito tarde, quando o mundo já não tinha mais tanto interesse no desenvolvimento desktop, por isso não tivemos uma adoção muito grande dessa tecnologia. Mas é simples, com uma identidade visual muito bonita, simples pra programar e consequentemente mais fácil.

Dessa forma, se você precisa escolher uma tecnologia Java pra desenvolver pra desktop, a escolha sem a menor dúvida é o JavaFX.

Comment: Essas já sabia mas mesmo assim valeu pela resposta! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: Mas você não pretende utilizar elas para desenvolver pra desktop?

Comment: Sim, pretendo com as biblioteca awt e swing pois não sei quase nada sobre a biblioteca javafx. Só queria saber se existissem mais bibliotecas  para tornar meu software mais dinâmico, eficiente e eficaz!